# Add signatyre field to PDF and use it on DSS

Tags: javascript, java, digital-signature

I have developed an online electronic signature application using DSS which works well.

Now I'm integrating a web application that allows users to position a signature area in a PDF (using Javascript) and then I get the X and Y positions.

The problem I encounter is that the positions I retrieve from the front application are shifted after signing at the DSS level.

May I know what unit of measurement is used at DSS level (originX and originY)?

What I'm doing right now is getting the positions provided at the web application level and converting by multiplying by 0.75 which decreases the lag a little but not top

Here is the source code to retrieve pdf positions from front application :

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Positionnement de la zone de signature dans un PDF</title>
  <style>
   
    #signatureZone {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 100px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 2px dashed #f00;
      cursor: grab;
    }
    #pdfContainer {
      overflow-y: scroll; /* Ajoute une barre de défilement verticale */
      width: 600px;
      height: 600px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #pdfPages {
      height: 100%; /* Remplit toute la hauteur du conteneur */
    }
    .page {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="pdfContainer">
        <div id="pdfPages"></div>

  </div>
     <div id="signatureZone"></div>
    <button id="prevPage">Precedent</button>
  <button id="nextPage">Suivant</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="pdf.js"></script>
  <script src="pdf.worker.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
let pdfDoc = null;
let pageNum = 1;
let pageRendering = false;
let pageNumPending = null;
const scale = 1.5; // Ajustez la valeur si nécessaire
const signatureZone = document.getElementById('signatureZone');
let offsetX, offsetY;
let isDragging = false;
let currentPage = 1; // Variable pour stocker le numéro de la page actuelle


// Gestionnaires d'événements pour faire glisser la zone de signature
signatureZone.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging);
signatureZone.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
signatureZone.addEventListener('mouseup', endDragging);
signatureZone.addEventListener('mouseleave', endDragging);

// Charge le PDF et affiche la première page
pdfjsLib.getDocument('exemple.pdf').promise.then(function (pdf) {
  pdfDoc = pdf;
  renderPage(pageNum);
  // displayPages(pdf.numPages);
});

function displayPages(numPages) {
  const pdfPagesContainer = document.getElementById('pdfPages');

  for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
    const pageDiv = document.createElement('div');
    pageDiv.className = 'page';
    pdfPagesContainer.appendChild(pageDiv);

    // Affiche chaque page dans le div créé ci-dessus
    pdfDoc.getPage(i).then(function (page) {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      const renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport,
      };
      page.render(renderContext).promise.then(function () {
        pageDiv.appendChild(canvas);
      });
    });
  }
  // Met à jour la variable currentPage avec le numéro de la page actuelle
  currentPage = numPages;
}


function renderPage(num) {
  pageRendering = true;
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function (page) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    const renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport,
    };

    page.render(renderContext).promise.then(function () {
      const pdfContainer = document.getElementById('pdfContainer');
      pdfContainer.innerHTML = '';
      pdfContainer.appendChild(canvas);
      pageRendering = false;
      if (pageNumPending !== null) {
        renderPage(pageNumPending);
        pageNumPending = null;
      }
    });
  });
  // Met à jour la variable currentPage avec le numéro de la page actuelle
  currentPage = num;
}

function queueRenderPage(num) {
  if (pageRendering) {
    pageNumPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
}

function onPrevPage() {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}

function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}

function startDragging(e) {
  isDragging = true;
  offsetX = e.clientX - signatureZone.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  offsetY = e.clientY - signatureZone.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}

function drag(e) {
  if (isDragging) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const containerRect = document.getElementById('pdfContainer').getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.clientX - containerRect.left - offsetX;
    const y = e.clientY - containerRect.top - offsetY;
    signatureZone.style.left = `${x}px`;
    signatureZone.style.top = `${y}px`;
  }
}

function endDragging() {
  isDragging = false;

  // Enregistrez la position de la zone de signature ici, par exemple avec jQuery AJAX
   const position = {
    page: currentPage,
    left: signatureZone.style.left,
    top: signatureZone.style.top,
  };

  console.log("position : ", position)
  // Vous pouvez ensuite envoyer la position au serveur pour enregistrement
  // $.ajax({
  //   url: '/votre/endpoint',
  //   type: 'POST',
  //   data: position,
  //   success: function (response) {
  //     console.log('Position enregistrée avec succès');
  //   },
  //   error: function (error) {
  //     console.error('Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement de la position', error);
  //   },
  // });
}

// Gestion des boutons précédents/suivants
document.getElementById('prevPage').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);
document.getElementById('nextPage').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just edited the question and added the source code to retrieve the positions. But my question in the first place is just to know the unit for DSS and for the front or the converter that must be put